# building custom packages in a user's home directory

Tags: package, nix, home-directory, nixos

I've noticed that any attempt to build custom packages in a user's home directory fails, due to the home directory permissions:

```
drwx------
```

coupled with the fact that `nix-rebuild switch` uses the `nixbld{n}` user.

Is there any way of getting around that? Can custom packages (user config files, for example) be built in a user's home directory, or is does this go against the underlying principles of NixOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can custom packages (user config files, for example) be built in a
>   user's home directory, or is does this go against the underlying
>   principles of NixOS?

No, you cannot build in a user's home directory because it goes against Nix's design. Nix performs the actual build in `/tmp` running as a `nixbld{n}` user and stores the output in `/nix/store`.

In general, NixOS doesn't provide a mechanism for dealing with user configurations. However there are exceptions, such as adding SSH authentication keys.

Comment: Thanks - is there documentation for the said exceptions?

Comment: No. The closest thing is the user-specific configuration options: https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#users.users In fact, I goofed the exception. Yes, it's user-specific configuration but it's not stored in the user's home directory.